# React form submission is triggering a re-render (despite e.preventDefault)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I just restructured my authorization form component to pull out the state-handling logic into a custom hook so it could be reused in other places. Prior to doing so, submitting my form did not trigger a re-render (for example, if there were validation errors), but now it does. To clarify, the page doesn't actually reload/refresh (so I don't think this is coming from the default form submit behavior), but the background image (which is coming from a higher-level container component) does re-render.

AuthForm.js

```
const AuthForm = ({ buttonText, formType, onAuth, history, ...props }) => {

  const submitData = () => {
    onAuth(formType, values, history);
  }

  const {
    values,
    errors,
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit,
  } = useForm(submitData, validate);

return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <FlexContainer flexDirection="column" justify="space-between" >
        <FlexContainer flexDirection="column" >
          <TextInput
            id="email"
            name="email"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.email || ''}
            placeholder="Email"
            onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""}
            onBlur={(e) => e.target.placeholder = "Email"}
          />
          {errors.email && <ErrorMessage>{errors.email}</ErrorMessage>}
          <TextInput
            id="password"
            name="password"
            onChange={handleChange}
            type="password"
            value={values.password || ''}
            placeholder="Password"
            onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = ""}
            onBlur={(e) => e.target.placeholder = "Password"}
          />
          {errors.password && <ErrorMessage>{errors.password}</ErrorMessage>}
        </FlexContainer>
        <FlexContainer flexDirection='column' >
          <Button type="submit" buttonText={buttonText} buttonSize="large"/>
        </FlexContainer>
      </FlexContainer>
    </Form>
  )
};
...
function validate(values) {
  let errors = {};
  if (!values.email) {
    errors.email = 'Email address is required';
  } else if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/.test(values.email)) {
    errors.email = 'Email address is invalid';
  }
  if (!values.password) {
    errors.password = 'Password is required';
  } else if (values.password.length < 8) {
    errors.password = 'Password must be 8 or more characters';
  }
  return errors;
};

export default AuthForm;
```

useForm.js (custom hook) -- taken with modifications from [this article](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/form-validation-using-custom-react-hooks)

```
const useForm = (callback, validate) => {

  const [values, setValues] = useState({});
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && isSubmitting) {
      callback();
    }
    else if (isSubmitting) {
      setValues({});
    }
  }, [errors]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setErrors(validate(values));
    setIsSubmitting(true);
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    setValues(values => ({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }));
  };

  return {
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit,
    values,
    errors,
  }
};

export default useForm;
```

Given that most of the code is the same (just relocated to a hook), I don't know why it would cause re-renders higher up the tree.

AuthForm is rendered by AuthContainer, which is rendered by AuthPage. AuthPage is where my background image is rendered.

AuthPage.js

```
const Background = styled.div`
  background-image: url('myimage.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 90vh;
`

const AuthPage = (props) => (

  <Background>
    <FlexContainer justify="space-evenly" padding="100px 40px 0 40px" wrap="nowrap">
      <AuthContainer {...props}/>
      <AsideContainer {...props} />
    </FlexContainer>
  </Background>
)

export default AuthPage;
```

Comment: What does AuthPage look like?

Comment: Added AuthPage to original post

Comment: And you're saying `AuthPage` rerenders on form submit?

Comment: The background image flickers and reloads, so I'm assuming that's what's happening.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the `onAuth` function considering it takes what looks like the history object.

Comment: The onAuth function hasn't really changed though and it wasn't causing the rerender previously. The only thing the history object does in that function is push to "/" if authentication succeeds. In the scenario I'm currently testing (failed authentication), the history object is never used.

Comment: Looking in my Network dev tool, there's another GET request to download the cached background image the first time I submit the form that fails its validation. Subsequent times pressing Submit does not cause this same behavior.